# How to forbid div enlarge its parent?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<body>
 <div id="id1" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; grid-template-rows: 1fr; background-color: khaki;">
  <div id="id2" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; grid-row: 1; grid-column: 1;">
   <div id="id3" style="width: 5000px; height: 3000px; background: dodgerblue"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="id4"style="width: 100%; height: 100%; grid-row: 1; grid-column: 2;"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

In my case "id1" div has size 1860px X 1340px. I expect "id2" and "id4" would both have 930px X 1340px size, and "id2" would have scrollbars because "id3" has greater size. In reality I get "id2" has 5000px X 3000px size, "id4" has 0px X 3000px size, and scrollbars appear in "id1", not "id2". If I remove "id3", "id2" and "id4" has expected sizes. How to make inserting "id3" not change the size of "id2" and "id3", but only lead to the appearance of scrollbars in "id2"?

This is simplified sample. In real life the size of "id1" is not known beforehand, so I cannot use 50vw X 100vh size for "id2" and "id4".

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand the body of your question, but I do understand "forbid div enlarge its parents", yes, sometimes a div is bigger than its parent, there are ways to fix this:

#### Overflow Hidden Solution

```html
<div id="parent" style="overflow:hidden">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

so you put the overflow hidden style on your parent, the child is still big but the only part of the child that you will be seen is the part that is within the parent's view box, the rest of the child is hidden. The attribute is on id2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head >
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="id1" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; grid-template-rows: 1fr; background-color: khaki;">
  <div id="id2" style="overflow:hidden;width: 100%; height: 100%; grid-row: 1; grid-column: 1;">
   <div id="id3" style="width: 5000px; height: 3000px; background: dodgerblue"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="id4"style="width: 100%; height: 100%; grid-row: 1; grid-column: 2;"></div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Overflow Scroll

This solution is like the one above but allows you to scroll to see the rest of the child element. I added the attribute to id2.

Here is the output of the code::

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head >
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="id1" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; grid-template-rows: 1fr; background-color: khaki;">
  <div id="id2" style="overflow:scroll;width: 100%; height: 100%; grid-row: 1; grid-column: 1;">
   <div id="id3" style="width: 5000px; height: 3000px; background: dodgerblue"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="id4"style="width: 100%; height: 100%; grid-row: 1; grid-column: 2;"></div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Summary

You have to look into the overflow attribute, it gives you a lot of options on how to deal with children that are larger than their parents. If this does not answer your question, comment below with a more specific question or edit your question.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the answer. Your variant changes visibility of scrollbars only, but does not affect on divs's sizes.

I noticed than "Run code snippet" button on this site shows different result comparing to making html and opening it in browser. I don't know why yet, but I guess this is because of using iframe on this site. I will explore this more.

Comment: Well, you probably have to get more detailed with explaining what you want, I don't get your question.